# iPad symbol keyboard on iOS iPad transfer to iPhone iOS 14.7.1

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, ipad

For years I’ve had an iPad symbol keyboard which I added in keyboard settings and would like to have it on my iPhone 11, but cannot find the third-party keyboard anywhere.

I can’t find in iPhone App Store, nor in a Safari search the same keyboard. I believe I downloaded it as an app to my iPad from a website, and then installed it so it could be added in keyboard settings. It works flawlessly and has more characters and symbols than anything out there and there’s no ads, no subscription fees, but just a free keyboard somebody put out there, and still works after all the iOS updates/upgrades. Mystery who created it, as no information is embedded anywhere that I can find when using the keyboard, nor in keyboard settings.

Is there a way to transfer a keyboard from iPad to iPhone? There’s no information who the third party is that I can find. Perhaps I am not looking in the right place?

It has a plethora of different types of  characters and symbols from all over the world,Meet me categorized in a long list when you click on it a whole different set of characters and symbols show up. Like having 100 different keyboards within one keyboard. At the top of the list, there is a frequently used tab which has symbols and characters added if you type one, 3 or more three times in a row. Absolutely awesome, with no annoying ads or hidden fees, just an old time freeware that works perfectly for at least past seven years.

Comment: You can't download stuff from websites for an iPad (unless you jailbreak it), so this app had to come from the App Store at one time.  Perhaps abandoned by the author since then.

Comment: Please post a screen shot.  What you describe sounds a bit like the app Unicode Pad (which is what I usually recommend to people who need something like this).

Comment: First question and looking to see how to add a screenshot. Yes, this would be the best way for someone to ID this keyboard that is in my opinion the best one I’ve used, and apply fora of different characters, symbols and languages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: List of 8 keyboards to choose from.]

Screenshot of first page when selecting keyboard - “Symbol”

Comment: The list you see there when you first select that keyboard scrolls down to reveal hundreds of sub keyboards from every type of language, character type, and symbol types. There are too many to find any one particular, so the frequently used tab at top you fill by typing a character three times or more. Is anyone familiar with this keyboard, or anything about it? It doesn’t show on my iPhone 11 as a selectable keyboard, and don’t remember how I got it included so many years ago on my iPad. I’m currently using an iPad five mini with the current iOS 14.7.1